# GROUP BY com ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

Como fazer um `GROUP BY` no `MySQL` respeitando os resultados obtidos com o `ORDER BY`

Ex:

```
ID(Primary Key) | nome | codigo | tipo
1 | Item E | 5 | 1
2 | Item D | 4 | 1
3 | Item B | 2 | 1
4 | Item C | 3 | 2
5 | Item A | 1 | 2

SELECT * FROM tabela GROUP BY tipo ORDER BY codigo ASC
```

Resultado obtido:

```
4 | Item C | 3 | 2
1 | Item E | 5 | 1
```

Resultado esperado:

```
5 | Item A | 1 | 2
3 | Item B | 2 | 1
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você precisa colocar em sua lista de seleção `tipo` e a função de agregação `MIN(codigo)`, juntamente com o `GROUP BY tipo`, e não tendo sentido este `ORDER BY codigo ASC`.

Comment: Deu certo usando o MIN().
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Solução baseada no comentário do post:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE codigo IN (SELECT MIN(codigo) FROM tabela GROUP BY tipo) ORDER BY codigo ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a cláusula [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) para retornar somente os resultados que não possuam outro registro com o mesmo `tipo` mas com `codigo` menor.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
  id     INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nome   VARCHAR(100),
  codigo INT,
  tipo   INT
);

INSERT INTO tabela(id, nome, codigo, tipo)
            VALUES(1, 'Item E', 5, 1),
                  (2, 'Item D', 4, 1),
                  (3, 'Item B', 2, 1),
                  (4, 'Item C', 3, 2),
                  (5, 'Item A', 1, 2);
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tabela t2
                   WHERE t2.tipo = t.tipo
                     AND t2.codigo < t.codigo)
 ORDER BY t.codigo;
```

---

**Resultado**

```
| id  | nome   | codigo | tipo |
| --- | ------ | ------ | ---- |
| 5   | Item A | 1      | 2    |
| 3   | Item B | 2      | 1    |
```

---

> [**Subqueries with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6EfFqvVjsWJwfLKNV6zsWE/0).

Comment: O select com HAVING não retorna nada.
obs: o GROUP BY tem que vir antes do HAVING